# Does Gaara belongs to Uzumaki clan?

Tags: naruto

In the series, it is said that *most* of Red Haired belongs to the Uzumaki clan. But I don't think that's the case for Gaara, but he got red hair. So question popped up into my mind if he's belongs to Uzumaki clan or is it something *mother-father-combination* thing?

Comment: Assuming that this statement is true: it is said that most of Red Haired belongs to the Uzumaki clan. It states 'most of the red haired' not 'all of the red haired'. Take note of that difference. Having read the manga, there never was a mention nor hint of Gaara being an Uzumaki clan member.

Comment: @W.Are If I recall correctly, I believe the OP has it backwards anyways. Most Uzumakis have red hair, not most red heads are Uzumakis

Comment: @Wondercricket Ah yes. my mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there are no straight facts that confirm this or not, I can only use contextual conclusion to answer this:

No, it doesn't mean Gaara is of Uzumaki Clan because:

1. If Gaara was of Uzumaki Clan, it would play a big part in the story and Kishimoto would've definitely use it somehow, but neither of Gaara's parents are implied to be from that clan.
2. [Sasori](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Sasori), as well as [his father](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Sasori%27s_Father), are from Sunakagure and have red hair so it probably isn't that uncommon among the Sand Village people.
3. There are other examples of characters with red/reddish hair that are not from Uzumaki Clan, like [Tayuya](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Tayuya) or [Karui](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Karui) so there must be more red haired people in the world.